# AngularJS throwing 403 error on sending POST data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My Angular app makes requests to an API which is open to other domains.

On making a `POST` request **without** the `data` field, the request gets completed successfully. Thus, `$http.post(url).then();` works. However, `$http.post(url, data).then() or $http.post(url, null).then();` does not. Request also gets completed using jQuery and Postman (a REST client I am using).

The error thrown is: *Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.*

Setting custom headers (like most answers on SO) is unsuccessful. Passing a config object with `{headers: {}}` OR modding `$httpProvider.defaults` shows no change in headers in Chrome inspector.

The issue persists after enabling the [CORS plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en), which means this has got nothing to do with the API.

What am I missing?

Comment: The request from Angular probably has a header that's not whitelisted in the CORS manifest. Try to add headers from the request made by Angular one-by-one in Postman and find the one that's bad.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my angular app using restws/Drupal.

Open up your network console and check the headers.. should find your request has been replaced by a "preflight" OPTIONS request
In modern browsers now, In a cross domain request an OPTIONS request will be fired first, before the PUT.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Overview

My guess is the API isnt configured to accept the options request.

I had to patch restws with a little hack to recognise the OPTIONS object and return back to accept the PUT

Comment: beg your pardon, not put.. post

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm sorry but I don't have access to the API, so can't comment about this. Glad you got yours working, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Just realised..

1) Is you CORS set up as wildcard (or "mirror" with the CORS module -) ?
I THINK an OPTIONS request requires a specific domain reference. 
I had to change my CORS headers to be Allow-access-control-origin>mydomain.com & NOT *

2) Additionally, are you headless?
Ive found using restws - I have to actually signin to my drupalk site & then do an api request to session/token to get the token, passing my auth credentials. 
If not signed in initially, I get a 403 access denied.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe may a mistake with the cors configuration.

If your problem is using tomcat server, you must config cors filter in the web.xml file with the following code:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization</param-value>
    </init-param> 
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name> 
        <param-value>*</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name> 
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I hope help you!!